# Onyx File System check has taken 5 hours so far 

Tags: disk-utility, ssd, scanning, macos

- Mac Mini M1
- macOS 13.5.2
- 2TB Internal SSD
- 2TB External SSD
- Onyx 4.4.3

I've always had good results running the usual Maintenance scan of Onyx. This time, however, it reported a problem with the disk and recommended that I should run the File System check. I did this at 12:28. As I type it is now 17:59, roughly 5.5 hours later. Some questions spring to mind...

1. Is this normal?
2. Would it be safe to "Force Quit" Onyx - is it just doing a scan or is it moving things about?
3. When Onyx says that it is scanning the Data volume, does this indicate that it is scanning the main part of the disk?
4. Why, oh why, oh why could the makers of Onyx put some sort of progress indicator in their app. I hear that %age displays are popular these days

Comment: Whether or not to stop it likely depends on whether it's just reading, or fixing. If it's fixing you don't want to interrupt it.

Answer (score 1):

## Many Hours

Full disk checks can take hours. While not specific to [Onyx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OnyX), this [The Tech Wire](https://www.thetechwire.com/how-long-does-chkdsk-take/) article confirms the length:

> The scan by `chkdsk` can take anywhere from 20 minutes to 6 hours.
>
> The size of the drive, number of damaged files, and bad sectors will influence how long chkdsk takes.
>
> A 1 TB hard drive can take 4-6 hours, while a 128GB or less may take less than one hour.

Search for [how long should a 2tb disk check take](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+long+should+a+2tb+disk+check+take) for more reassurance.

### Onyx

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OnyX) mentions:

> OnyX is regularly updated by its author taking into consideration users' suggestions and requests. To do its job, the program uses macOS's standard Unix utilities, allowing their control through a graphical user interface without needing the command line.

With regard to a progress indicator, consider [contacting the developer](https://titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html) directly and providing feedback.

Be aware that Onyx uses standard Unix utilities and may not have access to progress information. It will depend on the underlying tools' output, such as [fsck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fsck).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Graham. I'll leave it running overnight...

Comment: I ran it overnight. It's still running. No reply from the app author...

Comment: I understand that Onyx is free and supported by a single developer, Joël Barrière. If you need one-on-one support, consider switching to a commercial file checking tool.